# CSS issue regarding margin and position attribute?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I have this code:

```
footer {
    background-color: #359DFF;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: overline;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

On this page:
http://ltd.url.ph/
I'm working on a webpage for my school, but the footer seems not to fit the page, also, in the left side, there's a gap, which makes the footer look ugly, as there's a white stripe right at the beggining of the bottom of the page which is not supposed to be there.

Any ideas on how to fix that and make the width adjust itself on all pages ?     width:100% won't work for me.

Comment: There's no problem in either Firefox or Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the body styles, add

```
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

Then for the footer, remove the right/left padding by doing this instead

```
padding:25px 0; /*This gives a top/bottom padding of 25px, and a left/right padding of 0.*/
```

Also, it would look better if you did `text-align:center` for your footer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you add the footer padding you enlarging it so remove the padding from the footer and add it to the p.
then you need to remove the height 50px from the footer.
and for final touch set the p margin to 0; and set the padding to :0 25px;
this will give the same look in all browsers with out the need to calc() and other weird css rules
here is the cleanest code for it:

```
footer {
    background-color: #359DFF;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: overline;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
footer p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0 25px;
}
```

and you don't need the extra div to hold the p.

Answer (score 0):

```
This Should work for you:

html, body{
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;

}

body{


 margin: 0;padding:0; float:left; min-width:100%;
}
footer{
background-color: #359DFF;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: overline;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
position: absolute;
}footer p{width: 95%;}
```